# How to check if methods are being called when your app is on google play

Tags: java, android, debugging, methods, google-analytics

is it possible to get logs or something back from my app that has been downloaded on peoples phones. I want to check if methods are being called ?
Is it google analytics and android debuggable that I use?

Answer (score 1):

Find a logger library that can log to a database.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to elaborate please on your answer, or send me on a link to a tutorial thats shows me how to do this please. thank you